# AWS Ubuntu14.04 Instance mktemp fails on upgrade

Tags: upgrade

Have run into an issue with an upgrade using Ubuntu14 on AWS. This seems different to such probs as full /boot and the like. How do I rectify this?

```
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu4.2) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up linux-image-3.13.0-35-generic (3.13.0-35.62) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
The link /initrd.img is a dangling linkto /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-35-generic
vmlinuz(/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-35-generic
) points to /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-35-generic
 (/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-35-generic) -- doing nothing at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.13.0-35-generic.postinst line 491.
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-35-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-35-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-35-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-35-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-35-generic
mktemp: failed to create file via template â€˜/var/tmp/mkinitramfs-FW_XXXXXXâ€™: No such file or directory
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-35-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.13.0-35-generic.postinst line 1025.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.13.0-35-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-virtual:
 linux-image-virtual depends on linux-image-3.13.0-35-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.13.0-35-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-virtual (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu4.2) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-29-generic
mktemp: failed to create file via template â€˜/var/tmp/mkinitramfs-FW_XXXXXXâ€™: No such file or directory
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-29-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.13.0-35-generic
 linux-image-virtual
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I free up more space in /boot?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot)

Comment: I don't know how I could @muru 

abi-3.13.0-29-generic  config-3.13.0-29-generic  grub                          System.map-3.13.0-29-generic  vmlinuz-3.13.0-29-generic
abi-3.13.0-35-generic  config-3.13.0-35-generic  initrd.img-3.13.0-29-generic  System.map-3.13.0-35-generic  vmlinuz-3.13.0-35-generic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just solved the same problem on a Debian machine. It's not a memory problem (I figure that out after cleaning up over 2Gs of memory).

You may be simply missing the `/var/tmp` directory.

> failed to create file via template '/var/tmp/mkinitramfs-FW_XXXXXX'

1. `ls -l /var/tmp`
2. If it's not found then do `sudo mkdir /var/tmp`
3. Run the `vmware-install.pl` again.

And if you want to clean up your disk to free up memory, run

```
su /usr/bin/bleachbit
```

That'll free up a lot space taken up tmp and cached files. You can run Bleachbit from your pull down menu (sorry I'm on a Debian machine so I don't know where is it is on Ubuntu).  But that's not as root, so you'll get a lot of access denied statements.

Good luck